# Javascript - using match to find two words and return all text between them (in spite of line breaks)

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm a pure amateur when it comes to programming, and javascript in particular, but I'm trying to work out a problem and I haven't had any luck finding a solution through extensive Google search.

I'm writing a short script to take a block of text that is copied from a website that always has a consistent format/layout, but different results, and paste it into large text field.  Then you click a button and it extracts certain pieces of information from the text, and presents that information in a reformatted way.

I got it to work for a large part of what I want to do, but one section of the text includes multiple line breaks, and my match isn't working as a result.  When this match fails it breaks the rest of it as well.  Specifically I'm trying to pull the restaurant name, address, city & zip, and phone number from between the words "Restaurant:" and "Cuisine:" in the below text:

```
Guest Name: John Doe Phone: (555) 555-5555 Reservation Date: Saturday, March 14, 2015 Time: 6:00 PM Party Size: 2 Confirmation #: 1703515901 Restaurant: Café Boulud
20 East 76th St.
New York, NY 10021
(212) 772-2600 
Cuisine: French, American Message from the Restaurant: Thank you for making reservations at Cafe Boulud. FOR INTERNATIONAL GUESTS: Please leave your email address and full phone number in the space above. This information will be used to confirm your reservation with us. Our menu offers a wide range of a la carte options inspired by Chef Daniel Boulud's four culinary muses: la tradition, classic French cuisine; la saison, seasonal delicacies; le potager, the vegetable garden; and le voyage, the flavors of world cuisines.
```

Here's what I have written.  It works for all of the reservation details, but not the restaurant details:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>



<script>
    function getVal(){

        var val = document.getElementById('ta').value;

        reserved = val.match("Name: (.*) Phone:");
        date = val.match("Date: (.*) Time:");
        time = val.match("Time: (.*) Party");
        party = val.match("Size: (.*) Confirmation");
        confirmation = val.match("#: (.*) Restaurant:");
        restaurant = val.match("Restaurant: (.*) Cuisine:");
    }       


    function myFunction() {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=400, height=400");
        myWindow.document.write(restaurant[1]+"</p>"+"Reserved Under: "+reserved[1]+"</br>Date: "+
        date[1]+" at "+time[1]+"</br>Party Size: "+party[1]+"</br>Confirmation #: "+confirmation[1]

        );
    }


</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>



</p>


<form>
    <textarea rows="30" cols="100" id="ta"></textarea></br>
    <button onclick="getVal(); myFunction();">Get Value</button>
</form>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: it looks like the text block I copied didn't maintain the line breaks.  There's a \n after "Cafe Boulud", "76th St.", "10021", and "(212) 772-2600"

Comment: @georg You forgot a \n right before `Cuisine` in the text.

Comment: @Ninetainedo: yep, done.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match EVERY single character, you have to do something like `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*`.

In your case, your regex should be `"Restaurant: (\s\S*)Cuisine:"`
If I get it right, there is no space before "Cuisine" because there is a line break.

**Demo :**

```
Restaurant: ([\s\S]*)Cuisine:
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TXHDHbIuilUfPusx)

**HTML Live example :**

```js
function getVal(){

  var val = document.getElementById('ta').value;

  reserved = val.match("Name: (.*) Phone:");
  date = val.match("Date: (.*) Time:");
  time = val.match("Time: (.*) Party");
  party = val.match("Size: (.*) Confirmation");
  confirmation = val.match("#: (.*) Restaurant:");
  restaurant = val.match(/Restaurant: ([\s\S]*)Cuisine:/);
}       

getVal();
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Restaurant : " +restaurant[1]+"\n"+"Reserved Under: "+reserved[1]+"\nDate: "+
  date[1]+" at "+time[1]+"\nParty Size: "+party[1]+"\nConfirmation #: "+confirmation[1];
```

```css
#ta, #result
{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Text to parse :</h2>
<textarea id="ta">
Guest Name: John Doe Phone: (555) 555-5555 Reservation Date: Saturday, March 14, 2015 Time: 6:00 PM Party Size: 2 Confirmation #: 1703515901 Restaurant: Café Boulud
20 East 76th St.
New York, NY 10021
(212) 772-2600
Cuisine: French, American Message from the Restaurant: Thank you for making reservations at Cafe Boulud. FOR INTERNATIONAL GUESTS: Please leave your email address and full phone number in the space above. This information will be used to confirm your reservation with us. Our menu offers a wide range of a la carte options inspired by Chef Daniel Boulud's four culinary muses: la tradition, classic French cuisine; la saison, seasonal delicacies; le potager, the vegetable garden; and le voyage, the flavors of world cuisines.
</textarea>
<hr>
<h2>Result :</h2>
<textarea id="result">
</textarea>
```

Comment: I tried changing out the code, but it doesn't appear to be finding the match and taking taking the text that I need.  When I looked at the Debuggex Demo it's showing no match there either.

Comment: @Dave It actually works properly for me in both Debuggex and my browser. Maybe it is a browser issue ? Which one are you using ?

Comment: Hmm odd.  I'm using Google Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 m.  Perhaps I made an error when I edited the file.  I changed the the line to: restaurant = val.match("Restaurant: ([\s\S]*)Cuisine:");

Comment: In Debuggex the address isn't orange ? With "Restaurant" and "Cuisine" being yellow ?

Comment: It is, but it also says "Result: Does not match starting at the black triangle slider".  When I made the change in my file and tested it I'm getting a blank pop-up window (which seems to happen whenever the match doesn't work).

Comment: On Debuggex, the message means it doesn't match from the very beginning of your text (which is correct). The orange/yellow area is the actual match meaning that the regex is correct.

Comment: ok that makes sense.  I tried taking [1] away from the end of the variable in the document.write statement, and the value its showing is "null" in the pop-up.

Comment: I tried using restaurant = val.match("Restaurant: [^]*Cuisine:"); and it retrieves the restaurant details correctly, but it doesn't preserve the line breaks, and it ends up including both "Restaurant: " and "Cuisine:" which I don't want it to.

Comment: I found it but I don't know why. If you replace `restaurant = val.match("Restaurant: ([\s\S]*)Cuisine:")` by `restaurant = val.match(/Restaurant: ([\s\S]*)Cuisine:/)` it works properly ! :o

Comment: So close!  It's retrieving the restaurant name, address, and phone number correctly, but not preserving the line breaks.  It looks like it's grabbing all of the whitespace and non-whitespace characters, but leaving behind the \n special characters.

Comment: I edited my answer to display a snippet. I noticed two things : It works ! And why do you have `restaurant[1]+"</p>"` ? Why `</p>` ?

Comment: That's awesome!  I can see it working in your code snippet by I'm having trouble getting it placed correctly in an htm file now.  Function getval I know is a script in the header, #ta and # result are style references, and the lower portion is the body, but where are you placing the getval()?  When I put it in the header it doesn't seem to work.  The </p> was just for formatting to have the details look a specific way.  Not important to the solution :)

Comment: The call to getVal() should be AFTER your `#ta`. Thus, I'd suggest you to move this code to the bottom of your HTML ! :)